# Status : Failure -Test failed: no ocijdbc21 in java.library.path:

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

> Failure -Test failed: no ocijdbc21 in java.library.path: [/Users/MY NAME/Library/Java/Extensions, /Library/Java/Extensions, /Network/Library/Java/Extensions, /System/Library/Java/Extensions, /usr/lib/java, .]

I am using oracle 21.4.3.063 version and keep getting this error message.
I also went to preference-DataBase-Advanced and check "use oracle client" as what other said, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm having the same issue